# Подключение статичных библиотек Qt5Widgets и Qt5Core

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtcreator, qmake

На ПК, где в переменном окружении нет Qt5, программа не запускается с просьбой о названных в имени вопроса dll-файлах. Проект собирается qmake-ом, дела с которым никогда не имел. В `Makefile` не нашел строки `LIBS`, однако в `Makefile.Release` (и .Debug соответственно) имеется следующее: *разнёс по новым строкам для удобства чтения*

```
LIBS = C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Widgets.a 
  C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Gui.a 
  C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Core.a  
  -lmingw32 
  C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\mingw73_64\lib\libqtmain.a 
  -LC:\openssl\lib -
   LC:\Utils\my_sql\mysql-5.6.11-winx64\lib 
  -LC:\Utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib 
  -lshell32
```

В директории `C:\Qt\Qt5.12.9\5.12.9\mingw73_64\lib\` обнаружил файл `libQt5Widgetsd.a` с "d" на конце. Пробовал указывать его вместо имеющегося `libQt5Widgets.a`, но это ничего не дало.
Как подключить статику, уважаемые?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился не совсем тривиально: удалил QtCreator со всеми встроенными средами (MinGW, MSVC). Установил в MSYS2 все зависимости по [мануалу](https://wiki.qt.io/MSYS2), в частности `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-qt5-static mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5-static`. Установил QtCreator исключительно, как IDE: все зависимости тянутся к MSYS2. В настройках профиля указал qmake: `c:\msys64\mingw64\qt5-static\bin\qmake.exe` и - о чудо! - вышел бинарник не 455КБ, а 20МБ со всеми зависимости внутри.